# Why are the convolvers in the bicommutant of the pseudo-measures? ($CV_p(G)\subseteq PM_p(G)''$)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, topological-groups, operator-spaces

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. For $1<p<\infty$ let $\lambda_p:G\to\mathcal{B}(L^p(G))$ (resp. $\rho_p:G\to\mathcal{B}(L^p(G))$) be the left (resp. right) regular representation. $CV_p(G)$ is defined as the commutant of $\{\rho_p(s)\ :\ s\in G\}$ and $PM_p(G)$ is the weak*-closed linear span of $\{\lambda_p(s)\ :\ s\in G\}$.

In this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1073 it is stated that $CV_p(G)$ is the bicommutant of $PM_p(G)$. If I'm not mistaken, the inclusion $PM_p(G)''\subseteq CV_p(G)$ follows directly from the fact that $\lambda_p(s)$ and $\rho_p(t)$ commute for all $s,t\in G$, but I don't see why the other inclusion holds. Any ideas or references?

Comment: I have a feeling that may be an oversight on the part of one or both of the authors - you could try emailing Nico Spronk to see what he says. The reason I think this identity is unknown, in general, is that (a) I made this kind of mistake once and was, erm, informed of this at length by someone at a conference (b) see the remarks on page 8

Comment: I think -- but have not checked carefully! -- that if G is discrete, one can show with relatively easy approximation arguments that $CV_p$ is the bicommutant of the left reg rep, which would imply that it is also the bicommutant of $PM_p$. This might also work for unimodular G, by adapting Segal's original argument for the p=2 case (Annals of Math 1950) but I have not thought about this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm sorry, this is definitely a mistake.  I don't know where that claim came from.

As $X''' = X'$ for any set $X$, it follows that $CV_p = CV_p''$, and so also that $PM_p'' = CV_p$ if and only if $PM_p' = CV_p' = \rho_p(G)''$.  As trivially $PM_p \subseteq \rho_p(G)'$ (as you note) we need only show that $PM_p' \subseteq \rho_p(G)''$.

Spelling this out, if $T\lambda_p(g) = \lambda_p(g)T$ for all $g$, and $S\rho_p(g) = \rho_p(g)S$ for all $g$, then we want $ST=TS$.

Like Yemon, I can prove this claim if $G$ is discrete.

**Edit:** You can now find a full proof here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1073

Comment: "I don't know where that claim came from" -- BLAME CANADA

Comment: For a self-contained proof in the general case, see the last section of http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1073v2